# Asterisk, blacklist a number by country code or area code

Tags: asterisk

I have a problem lately, of getting crank calls at all hours of the day and night from overseas countries. I am trying to blacklist entire countries, by country code.  After googling around I have come up with the following solution, but don't think it is working... as I have tried substituting my own area code and that doesn't work.

Does the coding look correct?

Also, I don't fully understand the `[+]?1?` part, and would appreciate a breakdown.

FYI, I do have a working blacklist by number set-up,  so I know the `[blacklisted]` context part works.

extentions.conf:

```
;; same => n,Set(regx=^[+]?1?(215|609)[0-9]{7}$) ;; my test
   same => n,Set(regx=^[+]?1?(252|96|27)[0-9]{9}$) 
   same => n,GotoIf($[${REGEX(“${regx}” ${CALLERID(num)})} = 1]?blacklisted,s,1)

   [blacklisted]
   exten => s,1,Answer
   exten => s,n,Hangup
```

Examples of numbers I am trying to block:

```
+252616251444
+252616531860
+27612238445
+96893327281
```

The test number I am trying to block is `1-609-123-4567`.

Here is my extension.conf:

```
    [from-Provider]
    exten => _X.,1,Set(CALLERID(num)=${CALLERID(num):1})
    exten => 17025551234,1,Zapateller(nocallerid)
    exten => _XX./_+252X.,n,Goto(blacklisted,s,1) 
    exten => _XX./_+1609X.,n,Goto(blacklisted,s,1)
    same => n,GotoIf(${BLACKLIST()}?blacklisted,s,1)
    same => n,Dial(SIP/home&IAX2/droid&SIP/office)
    same => n,Hangup() 

    [blacklisted]
    exten => s,1,Answer
    exten => s,n,Hangup
```

This is the result of a call that should go through. It gets blocked and spits out this output until the caller hangs up.

CLI output:

```
    == Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
        -- Executing [17025551234@from-Provider:1] Zapateller("SIP/Provider_did10-00000080", "nocallerid") in new stack
        -- Auto fallthrough, channel 'SIP/Provider_did10-00000080' status is 'UNKNOWN'
      == Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
        -- Executing [17025551234@from-Provider:1] Zapateller("SIP/Provider_did9-00000081", "nocallerid") in new stack
        -- Auto fallthrough, channel 'SIP/Provider_did9-00000081' status is 'UNKNOWN'
    ...
       -- Executing [17025551234@from-Provider:1] Zapateller("SIP/Provider_did9-00000088", "nocallerid") in new stack
      == Spawn extension (from-Provider, 17025551234, 1) exited non-zero on 'SIP/Provider_did9-00000088'
```

EDIT (with noop added for callerid)

I replaced the dialplan with yours verbatim.  The problem is no calls get through.

I think I see my problem.  I need to include `exten => 17025551234,1,Zapateller(nocallerid)` because that is my DID.   I don't know where to place that.

Here is the CLI output. It is the same whether it's a call that should go through or should be blocked...

```
== Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
    -- Executing [17025551234@from-Provider:1] Set("SIP/Provider_did10-000000ec", "CALLERID(num)=16175551234") in new stack
    -- Auto fallthrough, channel 'SIP/Provider_did10-000000ec' status is 'UNKNOWN'
  == Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
    -- Executing [17025551234@from-Provider:1] Set("SIP/Provider_did9-000000ed", "CALLERID(num)=16175551234") in new stack
    -- Auto fallthrough, channel 'SIP/Provider_did9-000000ed' status is 'UNKNOWN'
  == Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
    -- Executing [17025551234@from-Provider:1] Set("SIP/Provider_did9-000000ee", "CALLERID(num)=16175551234") in new stack
    -- Auto fallthrough, channel 'SIP/Provider_did9-000000ee' status is 'UNKNOWN'
```

EDIT (extensions.conf):

```
    [globals]

    [default]
    exten => 1001,1,Progress()
    exten => 1001,n,Answer()
    exten => 1001,n,Playback(hello-world)
    exten => 1001,n,Hangup()

    [internal]
    exten => 100,1,Dial(SIP/home)
       same => n,Hangup()
    exten => home,1,Dial(SIP/home)
       same => n,Hangup()
    exten => 103,1,Dial(SIP/office)
       same => n,Hangup()

    include => default
    include => iax2

    [iax2]
    exten => 10,1,Dial(SIP/home)
       same => n,Hangup()
    exten => 11,1,Dial(IAX2/droid)
       same => n,Hangup()
    exten => 12,1,Dial(SIP/home&IAX2/droid)
       same => n,Hangup()
    exten => 20,1,Dial(IAX2/clive)
       same => n,Hangup()
    include => default

    [from-Provider]
    exten => _X.,1,Set(CALLERID(num)=${CALLERID(num):1})

    exten => 17025551234,1,Zapateller(nocallerid)
    same => n,Noop(CALLERID=${CALLERID(all)})
    same => n,GotoIf(${BLACKLIST()}?blacklisted,s,1)
    same => n,Dial(SIP/home&IAX2/droid&SIP/office)
    same => n,Hangup()

    exten => 442035551234,1,Zapateller(nocallerid)
     same => n,Set(regx=^[+]?1?(252|96|27)[0-9]{9}$)
     same => n,GotoIf($[${REGEX("${regx}" ${CALLERID(num)})} = 1]?blacklisted,s,1)
     same => n,GotoIf(${BLACKLIST()}?blacklisted,s,1)
     same => n,Dial(SIP/home&IAX2/droid&SIP/office)
     same => n,Hangup()

    [blacklisted]
    exten => s,1,Answer
    exten => s,n,Hangup
```

I have two DIDs.  One in the USA `17025551234`, and one in the UK `442035551234`. I have no trunk lines.

**EDIT** (CLI output using ESYSCODER's context)

I have replaced the entire [from-Provider] context with your context exactly as you posted it.    Then I dialed my DID number `17025551234`from a number that should not be rejected `17025550000` (obviously I am changing the numbers for privacy concerns).

The CLI output is as follows:

```
    com1*CLI>
        -- Executing [17025551234@from-Provider:1] Set("SIP/Provider_did9-00000012", "CALLERID(num)=17025550000") in new stack
        -- Auto fallthrough, channel 'SIP/Provider_did9-00000012' status is 'UNKNOWN'
      == Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
        -- Executing [17025551234@from-Provider:1] Set("SIP/Provider_did10-00000013", "CALLERID(num)=17025550000") in new stack
        -- Auto fallthrough, channel 'SIP/Provider_did10-00000013' status is 'UNKNOWN'
      == Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
        -- Executing [17025551234@from-Provider:1] Set("SIP/Provider_did10-00000014", "CALLERID(num)=17025550000") in new stack
        -- Auto fallthrough, channel 'SIP/Provider_did10-00000014' status is 'UNKNOWN'
      == Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
        -- Executing [17025551234@from-Provider:1] Set("SIP/Provider_did9-00000015", "CALLERID(num)=17025550000") in new stack
        -- Auto fallthrough, channel 'SIP/Provider_did9-00000015' status is 'UNKNOWN'
      == Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
        -- Executing [17025551234@from-Provider:1] Set("SIP/Provider_did9-00000016", "CALLERID(num)=17025550000") in new stack
        -- Auto fallthrough, channel 'SIP/Provider_did9-00000016' status is 'UNKNOWN'
      == Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
        -- Executing [17025551234@from-Provider:1] Set("SIP/Provider_did10-00000017", "CALLERID(num)=17025550000") in new stack
        -- Auto fallthrough, channel 'SIP/Provider_did10-00000017' status is 'UNKNOWN'
    com1*CLI>
```

What confuses me is that I must have the `exten => 17025551234,1,Zapateller(nocallerid)` line in order for the the DID `17025551234` to pick up.  Where should that fit into the dialplan/context that you are suggestiong.  Or am I missing something.  Is there another way to answer when my DID number is ringing me?  Sorry if I'm being thick here... I may be missing one simple point.

**EDIT**  (priority change)

With the following context the caller gets a message, "The number you have dialed is not in service"...

```
    [from-didforsale]
    exten => _XX./_1609123456X,1,Goto(blacklisted,s,1)
    exten => _XX.,n,GotoIf(${BLACKLIST()}?blacklisted,s,1)
    exten => _XX.,n,Noop(CALLERID=${CALLERID(all)})
    exten => _XX.,n,Dial(SIP/home&IAX2/droid&SIP/office)
    exten => _XX.,n,Hangup()
```

and this is the CLI output:

```
     == Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
    [Nov 24 09:08:13] NOTICE[2957]: chan_sip.c:23613 handle_request_invite: Call from 'didforsale_did9' (209.216.15.70:5060) to extension '13022323111' rejected because extension not found in context 'from-didforsale'.
```

I get the exact same thing with the line commented out `;;exten => _XX./_1609123456X,1,Goto(blacklisted,s,1)`

Isn't the dialplan sequence:

```
    1. get caller ID
    2. pick up incoming DID extension (I may have the wrong terminology)
    3. check caller ID for blacklist
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match caller id doing something like this:

```
exten => s/_+252X.,n,Goto(blacklisted,s,1)
exten => s/_+1609X.,n,Goto(blacklisted,s,1)
```

or

```
exten => _XX./_+252X.,n,Goto(blacklisted,s,1)
exten => _XX./_+1609X.,n,Goto(blacklisted,s,1)
```

More on pattern matching:
https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Pattern+Matching

**EDIT**

Example to block `1-609-123-456X`, where `X` is any digit:

```
[from-Provider]
exten => _XX.,1,Set(CALLERID(num)=${CALLERID(num):1})
exten => _XX./_1609123456X,n,Goto(blacklisted,s,1)
exten => _XX.,n,GotoIf(${BLACKLIST()}?blacklisted,s,1)
exten => _XX.,n,Noop(CALLERID=${CALLERID(all)})
exten => _XX.,n,Dial(SIP/home&IAX2/droid&SIP/office)
exten => _XX.,n,Hangup() 

[blacklisted]
exten => s,1,Answer
exten => s,n,Hangup
```

You can add also other patterns like:

- `_252X.` (for numbers starting with `252`
- `_96X.` (for numbers starting with `96`

If this will not work please add whole CLI log. Noop will show us what callerid is looking like in your PBX.

EDIT 2:

Both lines should have priority `1`.

```
[from-didforsale]
exten => _XX./_1609123456X,1,Goto(blacklisted,s,1)
exten => _XX.,1,GotoIf(${BLACKLIST()}?blacklisted,s,1)
exten => _XX.,n,Noop(CALLERID=${CALLERID(all)})
exten => _XX.,n,Dial(SIP/home&IAX2/droid&SIP/office)
exten => _XX.,n,Hangup()
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work.  It blacks all calls showing a continual loop in the CLI screen: 

`== Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5`
         -- Executing [16095551234@from-Provider:1] Zapateller("SIP/Provider_did9-00000041", "nocallerid") in new stack
         -- Auto fallthrough, channel 'SIP/Provider_did9-00000041' status is 'UNKNOWN'

Comment: sorry for the lousy formatting above.  I tried to edit it and got stopped by a message saying I only had 5 minutes to edit.

Comment: Added another example. Show your extensions.conf file. Bits and pieces are not enough to help.

Comment: I have added the extension.conf for the DID in question.  It is my present working extension.conf.  

Where should I place your extensions?

Comment: CLI log for it also will be helpful. Log in comment above does not match your extensions.conf. It is running `[from-Provider]` not `[from-DID-provider]`.

Comment: Sorry, actually it does match.  I changed it.  I changed it back to match my previous post.

Comment: I can post the CLI output, but where should I insert your lines?  Should it be before `exten => 17025551234,1,Zapateller(nocallerid)` or right after it?

Comment: If I put it before, It just rings through.  I will post the CLI output and edit the extension to show what happens if placed after.

Comment: So placed before(above) it doesn't block... placed below it blocks all calls.

Comment: No calls are getting through.  I need to accommodate a line to recognize my DID.  I added details under section `EDIT (with noop added for callerid)`.  I am on the road traveling so I may be slower on my ability to respond.

Comment: From cli log it looks like something else is executed in dialplan. Without whole trunk and dialplan configuration it is hard to resolve.

Comment: I have added the complete dial plan above. I have no trunk lines

Comment: Use my whole `from-Provider` context without any additions then show CLI output.

Comment: OK... I have substituted your `from-Provider` context exactly as you have it, with no additions or subtractions (pure cut and paste) ... I think the first problem is that It doesn't know to answer when my DID `17025551234` is incoming.   The CLI output and a few comments are added to the original post under `EDIT (CLI output using ESYSCODER's context)`

Comment: Try with this line changed priority to:

`exten => _XX./_1609123456X,1,Goto(blacklisted,s,1)`

and with it commented out. Timestamp in log will be really handy also. Are those logs from one call or many?

Comment: This is the log from one call.   I am getting results from the tests you want me to run, and will post shortly.

Comment: posted results under `EDIT (priority change)`

Comment: Check EDIT in answer.

Comment: YES!!! That did it.   Thanks for all the patient help.  I didn't quite get the syntax at first.  If I understand correctly the `exten => _XX.` replaces what I had `exten => 17025551234`, mine being specific to one DID, where yours answers both of my DIDs.